# SQL Server - summarize dates by a flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (though have access to SQL 2017 if needed) and have a table like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (recdate DATE, myflag BIT)
```

That table has rows for all dates in a range, the myflag bit will change off and on, something like this:

```
recdate    | myflag
2017-01-01 | 1
2017-01-02 | 1
2017-01-03 | 1
...
2017-04-03 | 1
2017-04-04 | 0
2017-04-05 | 0
..
2017-05-15 | 0
2017-05-16 | 1
etc.
```

but what I really need to get to is something like

```
period_from | period_to  | myflag
2017-01-01  | 2017-04-03 | 1
2017-04-04  | 2017-05-15 | 0
2017-05-16  | 2017-05-21 | 1
```

so every time myflag changes, it creates a new row and the previous row has the end date set (if that makes sense)

I'm sure there is an incredibly obvious way of doing this, but I'm about ready to bash my head against the wall.. i've gone back and forth with selects and subselects and inserts and updates into temporary tables, even trying a cursor (I know! but its a one-off query)

Comment: Check out LEAD and LAG. But you will have to progress beyond 2008 as it wasn't introduced until 2012.

Comment: Thanks Sean - I have an answer below, but I'll definitely check that out so I can hopefully learn something useful moving ahead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use a difference of row numbers for this purpose:

```
select min(recdate) as period_from, max(recdate) as period_to, flag
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by recdate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by flag order by recdate) as seqnum_f
      from @tbl t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_f), flag;
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain in words.  I find that if you run the subquery, you'll see why the difference is constant for the groups you are looking for.

If your dates are sequential with no gaps or duplicates or time components, you can do the slightly simpler:

```
select min(recdate) as period_from, max(recdate) as period_to, flag
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day, 
                     - row_number() over (partition by flag order by recdate
                     recdate
                    ) as grp
      from @tbl t
     ) t
group by grp, flag;
```

This is basically the same logic as the first version.

Comment: I added the gaps-and-islands tag.  It's an interesting realm because there are various approaches and you may have to try several for the one that fits (as demonstrated here!).

Comment: I'm not sure why this works, but I'll definitely do some reading on it as it seems like it could save me a lot of headaches in the future.  This approach worked for me in the test case I've tried it with.. thanks so much.  will mark as answer as soon as it allows me to